# localhost: 8080 for master- Site not reachable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

These are the following configurations I've done in spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=8080
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=8g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=512m
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp/spark  
export SPARK_MASTER_IP='localhost'
```

slaves.sh:

```
localhost
```

After that, ran command: `./sbin/start-master.sh`

Output:

> starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to
>   /opt/Spark/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-s.out.

Returns the command prompt. The output has no url as mentioned in the spark-standalone doc and entering `localhost:8080` shows site not reachable. When I try to run the master again, it shows that it's already a running process. I have set all the paths for java,python and spark. What am I doing wrong or is there anything more to be done so that the spark master UI is up? Or could there be something wrong with my proxy even though all other web pages load normally?

Note: I'm using Linux os and spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: The Spark UI is at 4040. Why did you try to remap it?

Comment: The port is not for spark UI (which would be at 4040) but rather for spark standalone UI. 8080 is actually the default for spark standalone UI. In any case, I would checkout the log to see if there is an error which prevented it from starting.

Comment: I changed the port to 4040 in the conf file. Yet both the ports 8080 and 4040 are not reachable.